# What to look for in a hosting company for a fully managed dedicated server?

Tags: web-hosting

We have a few dedicated servers and we want to move these to a fully managed environment.

We are probably looking at using some sort of Linux/Apache/mysql/tomcat/php stack on the server.  Those are the main requirements.  With about 10-20k hits a day.  (there are several servers in the same situation).

So basically we want our own server, want to be able to be able to load software (very industry standard stuff not whatever) if needed via raising a ticket or using a control panel.  We want to be able to create new database users, database tables, update htaccess on server and folders and all of the normal stuff that you might get in a $20 a month service.

Only difference is we will pay more for dedicated server, for more memory (32GB), and for support.

My question is what should I be looking for in a hosting company that will manage a dedicated server, but also allow some sort of ability for us to manage the individual sites and add new sites.  Is there industry standard terminology or do I need to be specific (I will before signing anything) when looking?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I already reviewed that.  That question/answers did not cover anything that was fully managed/dedicated as my question stipulates.  Do you want me to comment on an old question to rehash out what was missed?

Comment: That question is a catch-all question that is the only advice that we give out about finding hosting here. See [We need to decide what we're doing with web hosting questions](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/we-need-to-decide-what-were-doing-with-web-hosting-questions)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Not trying to be a pain its just that my question wasn't answered there.  So where do I get it answered?  Meta?   You can't do a catch all like that when there are specifics and things change but whatever just let me know.

Comment: We effectively decided that all questions about hosting requirements were off topic.  Rather than mark them as such directly, we close as a duplicate of a catch all question that may be helpful in some cases.  There is no stack exchange site where your question would fit.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  - OK I am surprised.  It would seem that those questions would be a huge part of the site.

Comment: Not an answer - but don't use godaddy.  Their "dedicated servers" are actually a bigger VPS and you don't have full access to all server settings.

Comment: @Steve - godaddy would never happen - been down that road with small business sites.  Also we don't really need to be able to change "everything".  Honestly it is a pretty easy setup.  If there wasn't so much bureaucracy I would have this set up in a few hours.